# How do I configure wordpress structure for development using git and composer

Tags: htaccess, git, composer

I've been developing in other languages and web frameworks and I'm now starting with a Wordpress project.

I'm used to using git and a package manager, but Wordpress development poses some unique challenges in this regard.

I've followed the outline given [here](https://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/).  My directory structure now looks like this:

```
wp
wp-content
.htaccess
wp-config.php
index.php
```

Wordpress is installed into `wp` using composer.  All plugins and themes are installed into `wp-content`.

To *build* the site I copy all the above files and folders to the root of my local Apache webserver.

The composer file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "myproj/myproj",
  "description": "Description of MyProj",
  "repositories":[
      {
        "type":"composer",
        "url":"https://wpackagist.org"
     }
  ],
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.9.8",
    "wpackagist-plugin/add-to-any": ">=1.7",
    "wpackagist-plugin/advanced-custom-fields": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "wordpress-install-dir": "wp"
  }
}
```

The `index.php` file contains:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

And I have the following settings defined in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content' );
```

When I go to the `http://localhost` nothing is displayed.  I replaced the content with a simple html file to test the webserver.

I am a bit confused when reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory as how to set up the `.htaccess` file.

Any help regarding the above setup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way I do it is to have a standard, manual WP install. By standard I mean dropping the downloaded version in my virtual host root, ie. `http://myproject`, and loading `install.php`. I usually `gitignore` all folders except `wp-content` or possibly `wp-content/myplugin`. Composer lives in my plugin or theme directory, because that is where the development is happening.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the benefit is of installing WP via composer. It's not a library, but a self-updating CMS. The only upside I can see is if you want to deploy your project, you won't have to install all the plugins manually. But maybe I'm not aware of something, so let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your advice.  I changed the build output directory structure to match the default structure of wordpress.  I copy the individual folders over with a script.  I quite like to manage wordpress just as any other dependency.  It makes it easier to update and deploy a new version.